# Is is possible to provide REST and SOAP and AMF (BlazeDS) services from the same WAR?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, blazeds, amf

Is there any issues with providing several different formats of web services from the same application server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I don't see why there should be issues. I've done this in WebSphere with no trouble. I can't see a reason why this should be problematic in other app servers.

The only minor complications I could think of could come from the particular frameworks you might chose to use for example Wink for REST and JAX/WS. These might in turn pre-req different versions of libraries, so you might need to take care with classpaths etc.